# Multiple date.min() validations for Yup form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I have two validations I need to run for one field in my Yup form.

1. The expiry date needs to be later than today.
2. The expiry date needs to be later than the issue date.

How can I structure this schema to allow for two min validations? Because currently this code isn't working.

```
date: Yup
  .date()
  .min(new Date(), 'Date must be later than today.')
  .min(Yup.ref('issueDate'), 'Expiry date must be greater than issue date')
  .typeError('Please provide a valid date')
  .required('Please specify the expiry date'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both the `test` function along with the `when` function to achieve this.

```
 issueDate: Yup.date().required();
 expiryDate: Yup.date()
        .test('checkDateInPast', 'Expiry date cannot be in the past', 
        (d) => {
            return !!(d && d > new Date());
        })
        .when(
            'issueDate',
            (issueDate, schema) =>
                issueDate &&
                schema.min(issueDate, 'Expiry date must be after Issue date.')
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create scheme for `issueDate`. And check with `.when()`:

```
issueDate: Yup
      .date()
      .required(),
date: Yup
      .date()
      .when(
        'issueDate',
        (issueDate, schema) => (issueDate && schema.min(issueDate, 'Expiry date must be greater than issue date')),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks that does make sense but for some reason none of my errors are being displayed after that change. My final scheme looks like this now, do you see anything wrong with it?
`expiration: Yup.object().shape({
    issueDate: Yup
      .date()
      .typeError()
      .required('Please specify the issue date'),
    date: Yup
      .date()
      .when(
        'issueDate',
        (issueDate, yup) => (issueDate && yup.min(issueDate, 'Expiry > issue date')),
      )
      .typeError('Please provide a valid date')
      .required('Please specify the expiry date'),
  }),`

Comment: @KobusCoetzee I don't see your code. And I can't say for sure where the missing.

Comment: This is wrong. This eliminates the first check.